# Android: How to show dynamic HTML string in text view using Java

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I have an HTML string like `"&lt;p&gt;ABCD xyz alpha beta gamma &lt;a href=\"/abc/efg/STATUS\"&gt; Status&lt;/a&gt; abc. Select \"Track,\" abc efg hij. Select \"yes\" to continue. Abc efg Hij xyz.&lt;/p&gt;"`

It could have multiple  and these are relative links (not complete)

I have tried following code:

```
htmlText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            htmlText.setText(Html.fromHtml(message, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString());
        } else {
            htmlText.setText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        }
```

But it only converts html code to html tags

```
<p>ABCD xyz alpha beta gamma <a href=\"/abc/efg/STATUS\"> Status</a> abc. Select \"Track,\" abc efg hij. Select \"yes\" to continue. Abc efg Hij xyz.</p>
```

How can I dynamically show this string properly as HTML text in Text view and capture all the  as hyperlinks that can capture the relative paths and pass them to a callback function?